# Get value in dictionary with a model pk in a Django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, dictionary

I have a problem with a dictionary that comes from a view (I'm currently working on Django), the code is like the following:

```
{{ dictionary.model.pk }}
```

The model.pk is the ID of the object, and the dictionary contains:

```
[ObjectID, some_number]
```

So, if I put: `dictionary.1` (model.pk = 1) I get the `some_number` that is the number that I want, but if I put: `dictionary.model.pk` it doesn't return anything, I think that the problem is that I have too many DOT's, but I don't have any other way to retrieve this kind of data, how can I solve this?

PS: The dictionary comes from context.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - note that `[ObjectID, some_number]` is a list with two items, not a dictionary.

Comment: It sounds like you are returning a dictionary of numbers, when you should be returning a dictionary (or maybe a list) of model objects. In your view pass: `Model.objects.all()` to your context and iterate over the models in your template: `{% for model in models %} <li>{{ model.pk }}</li> {% endfor %}`. An alternative would be to use Django's `ListView` class-based-view.

Comment: The dictionary is like "{[172,10],[123,5],[165,3]}" ... And I'm iterate an object  in Django template with for that contain this dictionary... In resume.... I want obtain the dictionary in for loop

Comment: `{[172,10],[123,5],[165,3]}` - that's not a dictionary.